# Jquery : Refresh/Reload the page on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which loads after a ajax call , on clicking  i want to reload the page (like i press f5)

I tried

```
$( ".delegate_update_success" ).click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

but it does a simple refresh, but my page does not makes a new request to get the contents. 
It should happen just like I am entering URL to get that page.

Comment: are those request cached>

Comment: `location.reload(true);`

Comment: Make you sure you do not redefine `location` variable in your code. Or (better), use `document.location.reload()`.

Comment: I think you should read this tutorial on [refreshing page using jQuery](http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/refresh-page-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You should use the `location.reload(true)`, which will release the cache for that specific page and force the page to load as a **NEW** page.

The `true` parameter forces the page to release it's cache.

Update :

Since `window.location.reload(true)` has been deprecated. You can use:

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Only this did: window.location.href=window.location.href; (source: Satpal).

Answer (score 10):

If your button is loading from an AJAX call, you should use

```
$(document).on("click", ".delegate_update_success", function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

instead of

```
$( ".delegate_update_success" ).click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Also note the `true` parameter for the `location.reload` function.

Answer (score 8):

Use `document.location.reload(true)` it will not load page from cache.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `window.location.href=window.location.href;`

Comment: None of the other ways worked for me. Thanks Satpal.

Comment: @Satpal Your answer worked for me. Could you please explain this bit of code piece by piece? Thank you. You were really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Use this line simply inside your head with

```
       window.location.reload(true);
```

It will load your current page or view.

Answer (score -1):

use `window.location.href = url`

Answer (score -1):

simple way can be -

just `href="javascript:location.reload(true);`

your answer is

```
location.reload(true);
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a less desirable solution than the accepted answer.