# How to reload a page from another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to reload a page (index.php) from another php file (script.php) if a condition is met. I am running script.php using jquery (not sure if this is jquery but please see below code) from global.js

Here is how they run...

global.js runs when a button from login.php is clicked

```
$('input#btnlogIn').on('click', function() {
var pword1 = $('input#user_pword').val();
var name1 = $('input#user_name').val();
if(($.trim(name1) !=='') &&($.trim(pword1) !=='' )){
$.post('ajax/login_script.php', {user_name: name1, user_pword1: pword1}, function(data) {
$('div#log_inerrormsg').text(data);
});
}
});
```

This is the code I am trying to workout -> login_script.php

```
if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($pssword, $results['password'])){
        $loggeduser = $results['username'];

        $_SESSION["uid"]=$loggeduser;
        //code to refresh index.php or a specific div inside index.php

    }
```

Below `$_session["uid"]=$loggeduser;` I need a code, whether a javascript or anything, that can help me reload index.php or a portion of a div inside index.php.  I am trying to change the header menu if a member logged in.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use in general function file

```
function user_logged_in(){
        return (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
```

and in global.js  in post() method callback  redirect user .. use

```
window.location.href = 'index.php' // the link you want user to go to after log in
```

and in your index.php code use

```
if(user_logged_in() === true){
   // code if user already logged in
}else{
   // user not logged in 
}
```

if you dont want to use a function just in index.php use

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
     // code if user already logged in
    }else{
       // user not logged in 
    }
```

**for more explaination**
you can't redirect user from php file which used by $.post() or $.ajax() .. you redirect in js callback function

Comment: Where should I write the function you stated? I am new in php and haven't got enough practice using functions kindly bare with me. in global.js.. can I just write 'window.location.href = 'index.php' ' there anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can write in login_script.php something like "OK" and check in jQuery:

```
if(data == 'OK'){
  location.reload();
} else{
  //write error msg
}
```

Or specify which messages you suppose to get from login_script.php.

More about `location.reload()`
[Jquery : Refresh/Reload the page on clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207781/jquery-refresh-reload-the-page-on-clicking-a-button)